# How to make policy transactions without billing center server up?

Tags: guidewire

I have tried to change the gosu class from IBillinPlugin to standalone plugin and tried. But am getting error in different classe

i have explained and expecting

Answer (score 3):

Out of the Box, it is not necessary to having a Billing System integrated with PolicyCenter. However, once your PolicyCenter code-base is coupled with the billing system, it may not be sufficient remove or change the plugin. In that case I recommend to stub in values to the appropriate class or integration.